# Open 3rd party Application with Python

Tags: python

I am on Windows XP and have a 3rd party application that I want to be able to open using a Python script. How do I go about doing it?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
mySuite = Dispatch("TestSuite.Application")
```

throws an error

```
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 312, in RunScript
exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Script1.py", line 2, in <module>
mySuite = Dispatch("TestSuite.Application")
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 98, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 78, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: What is this "TestSuite.Application"?  Do you have a link to the source, or something?  Googling doesn't turn up anything obvious for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the TestSuite.Application COM class has not been registered -- try opening it in, say, VBScript, to verify, and it should also fail.  In which case maybe you can fix it with [regsvr32.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) or similar tools.